# Surfaces calculator

Tags: python, calculator, polygon, flat

```
print("Quadrat, Rechteck, Kreis")

a = input("Bitte wählen sie eine Polygon.")
if a == "Quadrat":
    q = int(input("geben sie die seitenlänge des quadraten an:"))
    Q = q*2
    print("Der Umfang ist",Q,"cm groß")
else:
    print("Achten  auf die Groß und Kleinschreibung!")

elif a == "Kreis":
    z = str(input("geben sie die radius des quadraten an:"))
    U = 3.14159265359*(z*z)
    print("Der Flächeninhalt ist",U,"cm² groß.")
else:
    print("Achte auf die Groß und Kleinschreibung")

elif a == "Rechteck":
    q = int(input("Geben die erste Kantenlänge ein:"))
     l = int(input("Geben die zweite Kantenlänge ein:"))
     O = q*l
     print("Der Flächeninhalt ist",O,"cm² groß.")
  else:
    print("Achte auf die Groß und Kleinschreibung")
```

i want to caluclate the surfaces of polygons but i cant get it to work. polygons like rectangle, square and circle

Comment: Edit the question to show what happens (errors, output) and what you expect to happen.

Comment: Your two first “else:” break the if - elif structure. Else must be the last of if - elif - else .

Answer (score 1):

## i fixed it myself

```
print("Quadrat, Rechteck, Kreis")

a = input("Bitte wählen sie eine Polygon.")
if a == "Quadrat":
    q = float(input("geben sie die seitenlänge des quadraten an:"))
    Q = q**2
    print("Der Flächeninhalt ist",Q,"cm groß")

elif a == "Kreis":
    z = float(input("geben sie die radius des kreises an:"))
    U = 3.14159265359*(z*z)
    print("Der Flächeninhalt ist",U,"cm² groß.")

elif a == "Rechteck":
     q = float(input("Geben die erste Kantenlänge ein:"))
     l = float(input("Geben die zweite Kantenlänge ein:"))
     O = q*l
     print("Der Flächeninhalt ist",O,"cm² groß.")
else:
    print("Achte auf die Groß und Kleinschreibung")
```

Comment: Nice job – do you realize where you went wrong earlier on? Here's two tips to make this better, if you feel like it: (1) on "Groß und Kleinschreibung" (capitals and lowercase), look up how to *change* the case of a string; (2) on `float(input(..))`: you will get an error when you enter something-not-a-number. Look up how to *catch* that error. Both can be found in the official documentation of Python; check the [Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html).